# Amazon Product Advertising API - Showing prices and images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am currently investigating into the Amazon Product Advertising API and hoping to produce an XML response that contains details **including an Item price and images.**

This is a typical example of the URL I am using with the relevant parameters for searching on an item i.e ItemSearch:

```
        IDictionary<string, string> r1 = new Dictionary<string, String>();

        r1["Service"] = "ItemSearch";
        r1["ResponseGroup"] = "Images";
        r1["AssociateTag"] = "AssociateTag";
        r1["Operation"] = "ItemSearch";
        r1["Condition"] = "New";
        r1["Availability"] = "Available";
        r1["SearchIndex"] = "Apparel";
        r1["Keywords"] = itemToSearch;

        requestUrl = _signedRequestHandler.Sign(r1);
```

The above URL builder will give me a URL whose response contains images (as I'm using 'Images' in the 'ResponseGroup') setting this to 'Offers' would give me prices but no images, I want **both**, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Specify multiple response groups separated by comma.

`r1["ResponseGroup"] = "Offers,Images";`

Answer (score 0):

Change the response group like :
responseGroup('Medium,OfferSummary,VariationSummary')

Key : VariationSummary will give you price values
key : SmallImage, MediumImage, LargeImage will provide you image urls